# Memory not being released when Activity is closed

Tags: java, android

I have one main activity. It start another sub activities as Tab. On closing sub activities memory isn't released using by sub tab. Memory increases every time on opening other tabs.

After some time my application get crashed:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

public static Activity activity;

private Bundle saveInstance;





@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.activity = this;

    this.saveInstance = savedInstanceState;

    Application app = Application.getSharedInstance();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // super.onBackPressed();
    AlertUtills.showQuitDialog(Main.this);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) this
            .findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(
            this, false);
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(saveInstance);
    tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {

    case R.id.create_new:
    {
        if (CommonUtilities.isTabNotExist(tabHost, "NewProject"))
        {
            TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("NewProject");

            Intent in = new Intent(this, Activity_cretateNew.class);
            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            spec2.setContent(in);
            spec2.setIndicator("New Project");
            tabHost.addTab(spec2);
            tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("NewProject");
        }

        tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("NewProject");

    }
        break;

    case R.id.open:
    {

        OpenDialog dialog = new OpenDialog(this, "Open Project", false,
                OpenDialogType.CORELOG_OPEN);
        dialog.Show();
    }
        break;

    case R.id.menu_exit:

        onBackPressed();

        break;

    case R.id.import_las:
    {
        if (isCurrentProjectExist())
        {
            if (CommonUtilities.isTabNotExist(tabHost, "ImportLas"))
            {
                TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("ImportLas");
                Intent in = new Intent(this, LASImportWizard.class);
                spec2.setContent(in);
                spec2.setIndicator("Import Las");
                tabHost.addTab(spec2);
            }

            tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("ImportLas");

        }
    }
        break;

    case R.id.import_coredata:
    {
        if (isCurrentProjectExist())
        {
            if (CommonUtilities.isTabNotExist(tabHost, "coredata"))
            {
                TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("coredata");
                Intent in = new Intent(Main.this,
                        CoreDataImportWizard.class);
                spec2.setContent(in);
                spec2.setIndicator("Core Data Import");
                tabHost.addTab(spec2);
            }

            tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("coredata");

        }
    }
        break;

    case R.id.list_Data:
    {
        if (isProjectHasWell())
        {
            if (CommonUtilities.isTabNotExist(tabHost, "ListData"))
            {
                TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("ListData");
                Intent in = new Intent(Main.this, ListDataWindow.class);
                // in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                spec1.setContent(in);
                spec1.setIndicator("List Data");
                tabHost.addTab(spec1);

            }

            tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("ListData");

        }
    }
        break;


    case R.id.basemap:
    {
        if (isCurrentProjectExist())
        {
            if (CommonUtilities.isTabNotExist(tabHost, "BaseMap"))
            {
                TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("BaseMap");
                Intent inBasemap = new Intent(Main.this, Basemap.class);
                spec2.setContent(inBasemap);
                spec2.setIndicator("Base Map");
                tabHost.addTab(spec2);

            }

            tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("BaseMap");
        }
    }
        break;

    case R.id.logPlot:
    {
        if (isProjectHasWell())
        {
            if (CommonUtilities.isTabNotExist(tabHost, "LogPlot"))
            {
                TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("LogPlot");
                Intent intentLogPlot = new Intent(Main.this,
                        Logplot_Activity.class);
                spec2.setContent(intentLogPlot);
                spec2.setIndicator("Log Plot");
                tabHost.addTab(spec2);
            }
            tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("LogPlot");
        }
    }
        break;

    case R.id.show_hide_project_explorer:
    {
        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) activity
                .findViewById(R.id.explorerFrame);

        if (item.isChecked() == true)
        {
            item.setChecked(false);
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            item.setChecked(true);
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        break;
    }

    }


    return true;
}

private boolean isCurrentProjectExist()
{
    return Application.getSharedInstance().getCurrentProject() == null ? false
            : true;
}

private boolean isProjectHasWell()
{
    return isCurrentProjectExist()
            && Application.getSharedInstance().getCurrentProject()
                    .getAllWells().length != 0 ? true : false;

}



public static Activity getMainActivity()
{
    return activity;
}
}
```

Comment: Hosting activities in tabs has been deprecated for over two years.

Comment: please tell me other way for creating tab.Creating tab is our requirement..

Comment: Use fragments with action bar tabs. Or use fragments with `ViewPager` and `PagerTabStrip`. Or use `FragmentTabHost`. Or use regular views in a regular `TabHost` (instead of activities).

Comment: i am to much confused about your answer. i think all the ways you suggested have same memory issue as older tab.so which way is i uesd??

Comment: "i think all the ways you suggested have same memory issue as older tab" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly? Did you follow Gabe Sechan's advice and examine your heap to determine precisely *what* your "memory issue" is?

Answer (score 1):

Run hprof or another similar profiler.  If this is happening, the number of objects of your tab activites will increase.  See whats holding onto references to them, and then fix them so they don't.

Its kind of hard to debug this kind of thing without those hprofs.

Comment: i am using MAT but it is not useful for me.It shows lot of resources,Bitmap which is not created by me.

Comment: Those are the resources in your res/drawable folder.  Some are from you, some are from the system resource (built in icons).  Android preloads them for speed.  Don't worry about them, only worry about bitmaps you've created.

Comment: i am not creating any bitmap, I am processing only *.txt files, while processing i used java.io.FileInputStream for reading filse & fill data in our object and save them as object by using java.io.ObjectOutputStream  & set null all the objects. For every file processing there are 8-10 MB Application RAM memory increase & after 5 to 8 import my app get crased.